# Adding angular module to mean.io package

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js, mean.io

I am trying to add the angular-ui-grid module from npm (or bower) to a mean.io package:

```
$ cd packages/custom/mypackage
$ npm install angular-ui-grid --save
```

I then added this line to to `packages/custom/mypackage/public/index.js`

```
import 'angular-ui-grid';
```

and this line to `packages/custom/mypackage/app.js`

```
MyPackage.angularDependencies(['ui.grid']);
```

This seems to import the JS, but not the CSS. How do I get it to also bring in the styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add into your index.js:

import 'angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css';

you can see how it is done for angular-ui-select in the mean.io's app.js:

https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/05c63abae72635923eda07fefeac937b4e67790e/app.js

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I've spent most of the day being annoyed at the outdated docs/tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Link the css file(s) in `index.html`

Example:

```
//index.html
<html ng-app>
<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css">
</head>
...
</html>
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid#npm)

Comment: That does not work as the `node_modules` directory does not exist in the build output. MEAN.io packages up assets into the bundle as part of the build.

Comment: This is just an example. you'll have to locate the `angular-ui-grid` lib folder and include that file in your `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`packages/custom/mypackage/public/index.js`

```
import '../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css';
```

but seems hacky.

Is there something missing from the angular-ui-grid package definition that denotes the main css file or is it an issue with mean.io's build system?